# get_var does not return a value

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I use the following code to find the ID of the most recent comment. I cache the value for 3 seconds.

```
function get_most_recent_comment_id() {
global $wpdb;

$transName = 'mostRecentCommentID'; // Name of value in trans.
$cacheTime = 3; // Time in seconds between updates.

// Check if value is in the cache
if (false === ($response = get_transient($transName) ) )
{

    $max_comment_id = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT MAX( comment_id ) FROM wp_comments;");
    $response = $max_comment_id;
    set_transient($transName, $response, $cacheTime);
}

wp_send_json( $response );

}
```

Yet it keeps returning Null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Update your SQL query by removing one 'FROM'. There're two.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few potential issues with this line:

```
$max_comment_id = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT MAX( comment_id ) FROM FROM wp_comments;");
```

The word "FROM" is given twice, and the semicolon after wp_comments might not be needed. Try:

```
$max_comment_id = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT MAX( comment_id ) FROM wp_comments");
```

Comment: Hi, I think I have worked it out. I pasted the From wp_comments so that I was using a table others would be familiar with when answering this question. This is why FROM is there twice - it is not there twice in my code. I am actually using a table I have manually added to MySQL, and I think $wpdb does not know about tables added to the DB by users. Does this sound right to you?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Wordpress, just took a shot based on the SQL. I'd still try removing the semicolon after `wp_comments`, though; I believe I've had queries fail using PHP's older mysql interface when it was included.

Answer (score 0):

try passing $db object as parameter to your function

```
function get_most_recent_comment_id($db) {
$transName = 'mostRecentCommentID'; // Name of value in trans.
$cacheTime = 3; // Time in seconds between updates.
// Check if value is in the cache
if (false === ($response = get_transient($transName) ) )
{
$max_comment_id = $db->get_var( "SELECT MAX( comment_id ) FROM wp_comments;");
$response = $max_comment_id;
set_transient($transName, $response, $cacheTime);
}
wp_send_json( $response );
}
```

call your function with $wpdb object

```
function get_most_recent_comment_id($wpdb);
```